# How to make button in CSS independent from parent

Tags: html, css

I have main div block and "wrap" block in it with button "Go" in it.

If I don't set height of main block, this button is getting as small as it possible. But if I set the specific height, the button getting stretched vertically.

I want to have the button stretched independent from height of main div block.

```css
.main-action-box {
    width: 84%;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    /*border: 1px solid #f00;*/
    padding: 50px 45px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.main-action-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    background-color: #fff;
}

.main-action-box > .input-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-action-box > .input-wrap > input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.main-action-box > .input-wrap > .submit {
    padding: 0 25px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff6666;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.main-action-box > .result {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.main-action-box > .result > p {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    color: #333;
}

.main-action-box > .result > .link {
    width: 84%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.main-action-box > .result > .link > a {
    color: #ff6666;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main-action-box > .result > .link > .copy {
    margin-left: 25px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-action-box">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input type="text" placeholder="type type type">
        <div class="submit">
            Go
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
        <p>Wrong result</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main-action-box" style="height: 350px">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input type="text" placeholder="type type type">
        <div class="submit">
            Go
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
        <p>Result that I need</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these:

1. `align-items: flex-start;` from `.main-action-box > .input-wrap`
2. `height: 100%;` from `.main-action-box > .input-wrap > .submit`

```css
.main-action-box {
    width: 84%;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    /*border: 1px solid #f00;*/
    padding: 50px 45px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.main-action-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    background-color: #fff;
}

.main-action-box > .input-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-action-box > .input-wrap > input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.main-action-box > .input-wrap > .submit {
    padding: 0 25px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff6666;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.main-action-box > .result {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.main-action-box > .result > p {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    color: #333;
}

.main-action-box > .result > .link {
    width: 84%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.main-action-box > .result > .link > a {
    color: #ff6666;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main-action-box > .result > .link > .copy {
    margin-left: 25px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-action-box">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input type="text" placeholder="type type type">
        <div class="submit">
            Go
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
        <p>Wrong result</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main-action-box" style="height: 350px">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input type="text" placeholder="type type type">
        <div class="submit">
            Go
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
        <p>Result that I need</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. 
But for other people, please change in your description that you deleted "align-items" not from .main-action-box, but from .main-action-box > .input-wrap

Answer (score 0):

You should let flexbox decide how its children are displayed. So, remove `height: 100%` from the .submit, and set the parent flex (.input-wrap) to `align-items: stretch`.

```css
.main-action-box {
    width: 84%;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    /*border: 1px solid #f00;*/
    padding: 50px 45px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.main-action-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    background-color: #fff;
}

.main-action-box > .input-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-action-box > .input-wrap > input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.main-action-box > .input-wrap > .submit {
    padding: 0 25px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff6666;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.main-action-box > .result {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.main-action-box > .result > p {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    color: #333;
}

.main-action-box > .result > .link {
    width: 84%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.main-action-box > .result > .link > a {
    color: #ff6666;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main-action-box > .result > .link > .copy {
    margin-left: 25px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-action-box">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input type="text" placeholder="type type type">
        <div class="submit">
            Go
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
        <p>Result that you need!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```